# Email from Plone on Windows Server 2008 64bit

Tags: plone

I installed Plone 4.0.7 on Windows Server 2008 64bit, and tried to add a new user. However, when I checked "Send a confirmation mail with a link to set the password", the new user was not created. Otherwise, I could create a new user. When I tested my mail setting on Windows 7, there was no problem. I could create a new user and send a confirmation email. I also opened the TCP ports (25 and 587) on the firewall of Windows Server 2008.

Does Plone have a compatibility issue with Windows Server 2008 64bit?

Comment: No, there are no known compatibility issues with Windows Server 2008 64bit.

Comment: Are you using Exchange for your mail server? Unix services often need a mail rule created before Exchange will accept and route mail.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your problem is email-related. the transaction for adding a new user might get aborted due to problems sending the email with the link to set the password.

did you check your email settings in plone_control_panel? does the contact form (contact-info) work?

Comment: Yes, I checked the email settings, but the contact form does not work. On the other hand, when I test it with Windows 7 and Windows XP, the contact form works.